# Creating a syntax tree from a type string/ITypeSymbol in Roslyn

Tags: .net, abstract-syntax-tree, roslyn

Does Roslyn provide a way to generate a syntax tree for an arbitrary valid type string or ITypeSymbol?

For example, `System.Threading.Task` parses to a tree of

```
QualifiedName(
    QualifiedName(
        IdentifierName("System"),
        IdentifierName("Threading")),
    IdentifierName("Task"))
```

While `System.Threading.Task<int>` parses to a tree of

```
QualifiedName(
    QualifiedName(
        IdentifierName("System"),
        IdentifierName("Threading")),
    GenericName(
        Identifier("Task"))
    .WithTypeArgumentList(
        TypeArgumentList(
            SingletonSeparatedList<TypeSyntax>(
                PredefinedType(
                    Token(SyntaxKind.IntKeyword))))))
```

and finally `System.Threading.Task<,>` parses to a tree of

```
QualifiedName(
    QualifiedName(
        IdentifierName("System"),
        IdentifierName("Threading")),
    GenericName(
        Identifier("Task"))
    .WithTypeArgumentList(
        TypeArgumentList(
            SeparatedList<TypeSyntax>(
                new SyntaxNodeOrToken[]{
                    OmittedTypeArgument(),
                    Token(SyntaxKind.CommaToken),
                    OmittedTypeArgument()}))))
```

While I am in the process of writing a lightweight lexer for this use case, I wanted to know if this was provided by Roslyn already.

Update #1:
Final variant to minimize parsing based on the approach described by Tamas:

```
public static async Task<TypeSyntax> CreateTypeSyntax(string typeName)
{
    var options = new CSharpParseOptions(kind: SourceCodeKind.Script);
    var parsedTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText($"typeof({typeName})", options);
    var treeRoot = await parsedTree.GetRootAsync();
    var typeNameNode = treeRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<TypeSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
    return typeNameNode;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText` to generate a tree from any input. If you give it an input which you have control over, then you can get to the subtree that interests you. So for example now you want to have the syntax for a type. You can put together an input like:

```
@"class MyClass
{
  TYPE_THAT_INTERESTS_ME field;
}"
```

Then get the tree of it, and navigate to the field, and get the `TypeSyntax` from its `VariableDeclarationSyntax`.

Comment: This approach with a typeof () node seems like it fits the bill.

Comment: Do  you have to give Roslyn a complete C# program, or can you give it just a fragment?   (e.g., can I parse "a+b*c" by itself?   Can I parse a valid substring of the language:  "else x+2;"?  Which API calls?

Comment: I don't think there's an API to handle arbitrary input. There is error recovery in the parser, but that doesn't mean it will provide a valid output tree for everything. It might not even be possible to uniquely return a tree for an input. Consider `x+`, which is not a valid expression and can be part of `x+2` or `x++`. You might want to check out http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/ and see for a couple of inputs what it produces.

Comment: If you provide the SourceCodeKind.Script option as in the code example in Update #1, you can get away with smaller syntactically valid expressions, but as Tamas mentioned it won't work for everything.

Comment: There are syntax specific methods for parsing as well. `SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression()`, `SyntaxFactory.ParseName()` and so on.